# Why is this pygame-menu dropdown only displaying the first character?

Tags: python, pygame-menu

I'm trying to add a dropdown to pygame_menu that displays the days of the month '1'-'31' (or '01'-'31') however when I select the dropdown while running, it displays just the leftmost character. The most concise code that will run is below

```
import pygame
import pygame_menu as pm
import sys

from pygame.locals import *

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1100, 800
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.init()


my_theme = pm.themes.THEME_DARK.copy()
my_theme.title = False
my_theme.background_color = color_opaque = (50, 100, 200)


setup_menu = pm.Menu('', WIDTH, HEIGHT)
days = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']


####
setup_menu.add.dropselect('Days',items=days, placeholder_add_to_selection_box=False)
####

def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while run:
        clock.tick(60)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.display.quit()
                pygame.quit
                sys.exit()
                break

            if setup_menu.is_enabled():
                setup_menu.update(pygame.event.get())
                setup_menu.mainloop(WIN)
        

            pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The above code produces the following

[image]

[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `days` list. According to the [documentation](https://pygame-menu.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.1/_source/widgets_dropselect.html), you need to create a list of tuples:

The items of the DropSelect are:

`items = [('Item1', a, b, c...), ('Item2', d, e, f...)]`

- The first element of the tuple is the display text that will be shown in the dropdown menu to represent the option.
- The rest of the elements in the tuple can hold additional data associated with the option.

Also, note that if you create tuples with a single item, only the first character of each item will be displayed. For example:

`days = [('Mon'), ('Tue'), ('Wed')]`

Would display 'M', 'T' and 'W' on the dropdwon menu. So if you want to display the full text, add empty strings to each tuple:

`days = [('Mon', ''), ('Tue', ''), ('Wed', '')]`

Here is a working version of your code:

```
import pygame
import pygame_menu as pm
import sys

from pygame.locals import *

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1100, 800
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.init()


my_theme = pm.themes.THEME_DARK.copy()
my_theme.title = False
my_theme.background_color = color_opaque = (50, 100, 200)


setup_menu = pm.Menu('', WIDTH, HEIGHT)

# use a list of tuples instead
characters = [
    ('Kaboom Bot', 'Mech'), ('Impulsive Trickster', 'Demon'), ('Low-Flier', 'Dragon'), 
    ('Menagerie Mug', 'None'), ('Murcules', 'Murloc'), ('Tad', 'Murloc')]

####
setup_menu.add.dropselect('Characters',items=characters, placeholder_add_to_selection_box=False)
####

def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while run:
        clock.tick(60)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.display.quit()
                pygame.quit
                sys.exit()
                break

            if setup_menu.is_enabled():
                setup_menu.update(pygame.event.get())
                setup_menu.mainloop(WIN)
        

            pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: For the example given with "tuples with a single item": `days = [('Mon'), ('Tue'), ('Wed')]`.  Those are in fact NOT tuples, because a tuple with only a single item still has to have the comma in it, as `('Mon', )`.  What is happening instead is the same as bmgrice's original post -  is that the widget is using the str as its sequence, so 'M' becomes the title, while 'o' and 'n' become the arguments.

Comment: If you want a concise list comprehension to generate the tuples for all 31 days, you can use the following.  I set the numeric value for each day as the first argument in each tuple.  Modify as needed:  `days = [(f"{day:02}", day) for day in range(1,32)]`

Comment: @nigh_anxiety That's a good observation. So he could just use something like `[('Mon',), ('Tue',), ('Wed',)]` rather than the empty strings I suggested.